# How do you convert a Uint8ClampedArray string to an android Bitmap?

Tags: android-bitmap, getimagedata

Im using a custom WebView component in android to display an html page with HTML5 canvas.
Due to lack of WebView support for the getDataUrl from canvas function,
im passing the getImageData.data Uint8ClampedArray to webview through web view JavascriptInterface.
It saves the images as a dark blue image. Any ideias?

// html
    ...canvas id="canvas" width="20px" height="20px"...

// javascript

```
imgData=context.getImageData(0,0,20,20);  
webViewArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(imgData.data);  
webviewApp.procData(webViewArraySTRING);
```

// android

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int[] results = new int[1600];  
int[] icnt = 0;  
int width = 20;  
int height = 20;
int pos = 0, end;  
while((end = webViewArraySTRING.indexOf(',', pos)) >= 0) {  
results[icnt] = Integer.parseInt(webViewArraySTRING.substring(pos,end));  
pos = end + 1;  
icnt++;  
}
```

// create image - tried using ARGB_8888, ARGB_4444

```
System.out.println("results size:" + icnt); // prints out 1599  
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  
bitmap.setPixels(results, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
```

// save image  `

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file,true);  
os.write(boas.toByteArray());
```